# How can I put a checklist button in a views table to run some code on selected rows?

Tags: 7, views

I want to select some rows in views table and run some code for selected rows(nodes) by submit button.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the [views bulk operation](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.

Comment: great answer but can i add a new operation that i want to applied to selected nodes?

Comment: @abd you can create operations in a custom module.